# Cloud9 browser preview address bar not updating

Tags: cloud9-ide

I'm not sure if this is a bug with Cloud9 or if it's the way it's supposed to work so I'm checking here first.

To keep things as simple as possible, let's say I create an index.html file which contains a link to go to inside.html

Then, I select "Run Project" and the index.html file displays inline with the URL in the address bar showing "https://php-userid.c9.io" as it should.

I then click on the link and am taken to inside.html but the problem is that the inline address bar does not update with the new URL.

On top of that, if I hit refresh, it refreshes index.html rather than inside.html as I would expect.

I realize that there may be a good reason for all of this but from my own personal perspective, I often need to know what the current URL is during development in order to properly debug my app.

Comment: Can you reproduce the same behavior when you access your project in another browser tab? or is it isolated to just the preview pane within Cloud9 IDE?

Comment: It's just the preview pane within the Cloud9 IDE. If I "pop out" the preview pane onto a regular browser tab then it works properly.

Comment: Hmm, can you please write to support@c9.io about this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I opened a ticket with C9 and they confirmed that although this is not how they want it to work, it's the only way that it can work for technical reasons.

This problem will hopefully be solved when C9 release their multi-platform desktop client in the future.